# angular 2 in a war : 404 error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've generated my project with angular-cli. I've created a new Java maven project, launched the "ng build" command, and copy the dist/ folder content into my java project webapp/ folder.
When I try to access "http://localhost:8080/hsmt-front/" I got a 404 error for every js script.
What am I supposed to do?
Also my routes are :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardPageComponent
},
{
  path: 'account', component: DashboardPageComponent
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Should I include the "hsmt-front" in my routes, like hsmt-front/dashboard, hsmt-front/account  ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

By default base URL is set as (/) or root.
Edit the base in index.html to be like :

```
<base href="./">
```